# How to deal with child's overflowing border out of it's parent container?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to figure out what are ways to stop borders from overflowing from it's parent container.

The only solution that I can come up is to set childs width and height by using `calc()` to calculate and subtract width and height of child's border.

Is there any better ways with dealing with this?

What solution would be suitable for pre-IE8?

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PD9NZ/) example.

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
    background-color: purple;
}

.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One option is to set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the child, which forces the border to be considered part of the child element's "box", rather than just the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dlev said:

One option is to set box-sizing: border-box; on the child, which forces the border to be considered part of the child element's "box", rather than just the content.

But even if you one to use calc css method then just deduct the border size:

```
.child {
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    height: calc(100% - 5px);
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PD9NZ/8/)

Answer (score 2):

you have set the width and height of child element to 100 percent so obviously it will be equal to the container one. Now setting a border,it will take extra width and height that will overflow.

so the first solution is the changing dimensions.

```
.child {
width: 90%;
height: 90%;
border: 5px solid red;
```

}

Note-90% is only in this case.

and the other solution is

`.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid red;
box-sizing:border-box;}`